# code navigation not working for scala file in intellij

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

In my scala project in intellij, I see some files have symbol like this:

[image]

In these files, code navigation(ctrl+b) is not working.

What is this symbol for? Any does it have any connection with navigation not working?

Comment: Sounds like these files are not "interpreted". Is the directory they are in (or one of its parent) flagged as a "source directory"? If not, you can force it manually, right click > Mark as...

Comment: There is a 'src' directory marked as 'source directory'.

Comment: Can you share a project structure screenshot? What's the content in that file?